# Split video into pictures

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-converter

I need software that can take a standard .mp4 video and give me all the frames in standard picture format (.png or .jpg if possible). I know Movie Maker can take individual frames and turn them into pictures but I need an automated program if at all possible.

I'm trying to do this on the Windows OS (7/8) and I need a program that is free to use (no shareware).

Comment: Mind to give some additional details (see e.g. [here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for some improvement hints)? Especially: What OS should it run on? Is "image splitting" the only requirement? What's the budget (or must it be free)?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), [Mac](http://ffmpegmac.net/) and Linux
- Allows to [split video into pictures](https://superuser.com/a/729351/116475): e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 0.25 output_%04d.png` to get a picture every four seconds.
- Is CLI so you can batch.
- Supports most of the video formats.

Other [ideas](https://superuser.com/q/135117/116475).

Comment: I suggest using the command line for "every frame" as per the OP's question, which is just dropping the `-r 0.25` I think

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer to have a graphical user interface and need to export every frame, you can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/):

- free and open source
- Windows
- File -> Export -> Image sequence:

[image]

Comment: It looks like this would fit the job.

Comment: Just verified that this does work. You may need to look around for the additional FFMpeg input plugins depending on the video type you are working with.