# Brightness histogram of a video

Tags: video, image-processing, signal-processing

I want an histogram of the brightness of a video.

I define [brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness) of an image as the sum of RGB values of all its pixels, divided by 3, divided by the number of pixels.

The program would calculate this brightness value for each frame of the video, then draw an histogram that could look like this:

```
Brightness                 __
 ^                 _      /
 |                / \    /      
 |__             /   \__/           
 |  \___        /                 
 |      \______/                     
 |                           
 +---------------------------> Time
 Start                      End
```

Free, or at least free trial, ideally open source.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: [Split video into frames](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6783/903)

Step 2: As you know, there are many definitions of brightness:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/596216/395857
- http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx

You can compute the brightness in any language e.g. in Matlab:

```
[X,map] = imread('corn.tif'); % Read image
Im = ind2rgb(X,map); % convert the data in X to RGB.
brightness = mean2(Im); % using your formula.
```