# Convert video to APNG

Tags: video, animation, png

I'm looking for an application that converts any video into animated PNG format (aka. [APNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG)).

The application should read MKV files as well as other popular formats and allow to select:

- Dimensions of resulting animation in pixels
- Framerate
- Compression options
- Target file size
- (bonus) Subtitle for embedding

I noticed that APNGs are usually significantly smaller than animated GIFs (by about 10-20%) while also showing much better colors (>256 colors, no dithering or slopy gradients) so I'm thinking of switching to that if I can find a good app.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1. [split into PNGs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6784/903):  e.g. with [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) `ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 0.25 output_%04d.png` (to get a picture every four seconds in this example).
2. [resize the PNGs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7272/903): e.g. with  [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php): `mogrify -resize 30x30% *.png` (to 30% in this example)
3. Create APNG file from a bunch of PNGs: e.g. using [APNG Edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/apng-edit/).

---

- To add text to an image using ImageMagick, see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/
- With FFmpeg, you can [burn text subtitles (hardsubs)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo) with one of two filters: subtitles or ass, E.g. `ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.avi` or `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=video.mkv out.avi`.

Comment: is it possible to emded subtitles like that?

Comment: @user64308 yes, added in answer. You might have to script around though.

Comment: I meant while splitting video into PNGs, like making screenshots of a video player with subs on, but automatically, in a command line. Manually retyping text and using an external tool to paste it in will produce a different result and I'd like to achieve a "media player with subs on" animation feel.

Comment: @user64308 yes, added in answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VirtualDub APNG Mod](http://vdubapngmod.sourceforge.net/):

- free and open source
- it is a VirtualDub Mod so you have access to all VirtualDub features such as changing the FPS  or change dimensions (i.e. resize):

[image]

[image]

- handle APNG:

[image]

[image]

- compatible with major video formats such as .mkv files: you need to download some import plugins/filters. I personally use the [FFMPEG Input Driver](https://code.google.com/p/ffinputdriver/) (32-bit, I had issues with 64-bit) which provides support for 31 video formats

Comment: afaik Virtualdub doesn't read MKV, nor does it allow to embed subtitles, but I know there is a Virtualdub MKV version with limited capabilities, which I don't suppose can convert to APNG

Comment: http://forums.virtualdub.org/index.php?act=ST&f=7&t=20025

Comment: does it mean I can make this version support MKV and other formats by installing a plugin/filter or…?

Comment: @user64308 yes, added in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ezgif now supports video to APNG conversions.

http://ezgif.com/video-to-apng

You can upload any video format supported by ffmpeg, and select duration, resolution and frames per second.

Comment: Unfortunately I can never get their chroma key alpha transparency effect to work.